# Unable to remove space between rows in html table

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm trying to load a contiguous set of placeholders in a table and dynamically add an image control to all cells.  Then display it as a map.  I want no spacing or gaps between cells or rows.  I've had this working on a prototype I had done but now in the real project somehow I get a space between every table row.

I have tried many things.  I currently have the following style above the table

```
      <style type="text/css"> 
          * { margin:0; padding:0; font-size:12px}
    table { 
            border-collapse: collapse; 
            border-spacing: 0;
            margin: 0 0 0 0;
            padding:0;
            border: none;
            height:auto                
        } 
        td { 
            border: none; 
            padding:0px;               
            margin: 0 0 0 0;
            padding: 0;
            height:auto                       
        } 
        tr { 
            border: none; 
            padding:0px;               
            margin: 0 0 0 0;
            padding: 0;
            height:auto                       
        } 
        h1, h2 {margin:0;}

    </style>
```

I've taken a portion of the code and reproduced the problem on smaller scale.  ASP code is as follows:

```
    <div>
<table id="MapTable" style="border-collapse: collapse"  runat="server" >
<tr>
   <td><asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph1" runat="server"/></td> 
    <td><asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph2" runat="server"/></td>
    <td><asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph3" runat="server"/></td>

       <td><asp:Button ID="btnLoadImage" runat="server" Text="Load" OnClick="btnLoadImage_Click" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph4" runat="server"/></td>
    <td><asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph5" runat="server"/></td>
    <td><asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph6" runat="server"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
    </div>
</form>
```

//The C# code behind is also simple.  Just loads an image into each cell.

```
        ImageMap im = new ImageMap();
        im.ImageUrl = "~/Images/PlainsGrass.png";
        ph1.Controls.Add(im);

        ImageMap im2 = new ImageMap();
        im2.ImageUrl = "~/Images/PlainsGrass.png";
        ph2.Controls.Add(im2);
        ImageMap im3 = new ImageMap();
        im3.ImageUrl = "~/Images/PlainsGrass.png";
        ph3.Controls.Add(im3);
        ImageMap im4 = new ImageMap();
        im4.ImageUrl = "~/Images/PlainsGrass.png";
        ph4.Controls.Add(im4);
        ImageMap im5 = new ImageMap();
        im5.ImageUrl = "~/Images/PlainsGrass.png";
        ph5.Controls.Add(im5);
        ImageMap im6 = new ImageMap();
        im6.ImageUrl = "~/Images/PlainsGrass.png";
        ph6.Controls.Add(im6);
```

Spacing between cells is gone but I can't get rid of the space between each row

Here is an small image of what it's doing:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N45ct.png)

Comment: Could be your photo. check if your photo has some kind of padding or margin inside.

Comment: Also try to set css for image. set padding and margin 0 to image inside TD tag. this trick can help to to get rid of space between row.

Comment: Thanks for response.  It's not a problem with image.  The images are 32/32 bit pixel images that I created.   I tried adding 
            img { padding: 0; margin: 0; } to the style but had no effect.  Just to mention again.  I copied this page from another prototype project I had created where I didn't have this issue.  It had a lot of boiler plate (including css) from the Visual Studio IDE generating default web application that I had cleaned up in the new project.

Comment: After much experimenting and pain I found something that solved my problem.  In addition to setting the other normal padding and margin, collapsible border...I had to add  style="line-height:0;" to my table.